# Show String Data in Message Box C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, messagebox

It seems I've lost all basic coding knowledge but if I want a `MessageBox` to show the 3 string input in C# how would I approach that?

```
string city;
string zip;
string state;

city = txtCity.Text;
zip = txtZipCode.Text;
state = txtState.Text;

MessageBox.Show("City,State,Zip:");
```

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(City + " " + State + " " + Zip);`

Comment: MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", city, state, zip));

Comment: Ah of course its something way simpler than I was thinking. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}:", city, zip, state));
```

This go replace `{0}` with the variable city, `{1}`with the variable zip and `{3}` with state.

> `String.Format` converts the value of objects to strings based on the formats specified and inserts them into another string.

<sup>If you are new, read [getting started with the `String.Format` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx#Starting)</sup>

New in C# 6 is this:

```
MessageBox.Show($"{city}, {zip}, {state}");
```

<sup>Commented by @Lucas Trzesniewski</sup>

---

Another opinion is use this:

```
MessageBox.Show(city + ", " + zip  + ", " + state);
```

Just past it all together.

Comment: Is there an advantage to filling in strings this way? (stated with a numerical value and passed after the comma?)

Comment: @EyeSeeSharp: By `String.Format()` are there many overloads. You can also use `FormatProviders`. Also on the stack and heap are there differences between the two options. Documentation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Or `MessageBox.Show($"{city}, {zip}, {state}")` in C# 6.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: how is the backwards compatibility from C# 6 to C# 5?

Comment: @Hein pretty good in my experience. I came across a bug in the compiler though, but the code used an unusual syntax.